# \glsentryfmt definition causing \Gls not to capitalise first letter of term

Tags: glossaries

I'm using the `glossaries` package, and I have modified the `\glsentryfmt` to italicise terms on first use. However, this causes the output of `\Gls` and `\gls` to be identical. If I remove the `\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{...}` bit, everything works fine. I've read the user manual, but I don't understand how to fix it. Is this fixable?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse} % Hide some useless warning messages
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setromanfont{URW Palladio L}
\setsansfont{Droid Sans}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontface\amysipa{DejaVu Serif}

\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \ifglsused{\glslabel}{\glslabel}{\emph{\glslabel}}%
}

\newglossaryentry{wombat}
{
  name={wombat},
  description={blah blah blah}
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\gls{wombat} should be all lowercase.

\Gls{wombat} should begin with an uppercase letter, but it doesn't!

Wombat.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Not only do you include a bunch of entirely irrelevant font stuff, but you add `quiet` so that people don't get any useful information if the set-up doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably Nicola Talbot will provide a far superior solution. (And likely a safer one.)

Note that I minimised your example a bit as much of it seemed irrelevant.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \ifglsused{\glslabel}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\em}\glsgenentryfmt\endgroup
}

\newglossaryentry{wombat}
{
  name={wombat},
  description={blah blah blah}
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\gls{wombat} should be all lowercase.

\Gls{wombat} should begin with an uppercase letter, but it doesn't!

Wombat.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: Wombats wombating wildly]

Answer (score 2):

(Following on from [@cfr's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330895).) The `\glsentryfmt` command needs to know how the entry was referenced (whether `\gls`, `\Gls`, `\GLS`, `\glspl`, `\Glspl`, `\GLSpl` or `\glsdisp` was used). The placeholder command `\glslabel` refers to the entry's label. This means that your code

```
\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \ifglsused{\glslabel}{\glslabel}{\emph{\glslabel}}%
}
```

will display the *label* if the entry has been used and the emphasized *label* on first used. This disregards everything about the single or plural or case-changing requirements.

The [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330895) is a quick method and works fine, but here's a more detailed version that shows the decision making used by `\glsgenentryfmt` with modifications that add `\emph` for the first use. (`\glsinsert` is the text for insertion in the final optional argument of commands like `\gls`. For example the `'s` in `The \gls{wombat}['s] hat.`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \ifdefempty\glscustomtext
  {% not using \glsdisp
    \glsifplural
    {% using one of the plural forms (\glspl, \Glspl or \GLSpl)
      \glscapscase
      {% no-case changing (\glspl)
        \ifglsused\glslabel
        {% entry has been used so we want the "plural" field
          \glsentryplural{\glslabel}\glsinsert
        }%
        {% entry hasn't been used so we want the "firstplural" field
         % and add \emph
          \emph{\glsentryfirstplural{\glslabel}\glsinsert}%
        }%
      }%
      {% first-letter upper case (\Glspl)
        \ifglsused\glslabel
        {% entry has been used so we want the "plural" field with the 
         % first letter converted to upper case.
           \Glsentryplural{\glslabel}\glsinsert
        }%
        {% entry hasn't been used so we want the "firstplural" field with the 
         % first letter converted to upper case and add \emph.
           \emph{\Glsentryfirstplural{\glslabel}\glsinsert}%
        }%
      }%
      {% all upper case (\GLSpl)
        \ifglsused\glslabel
        {% entry has been used so we want the "plural" field converted to 
         % upper case
          \mfirstucMakeUppercase
             {\glsentryplural{\glslabel}\glsinsert}%
        }%
        {% entry hasn't been used so we want the "firstplural" field 
         % converted to upper case (and add \emph)
          \emph{\mfirstucMakeUppercase
             {\glsentryfirstplural{\glslabel}\glsinsert}}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
    {% singular form (\gls or \Gls or \GLS)
      \glscapscase
      {% no case-changing (\gls)
        \ifglsused\glslabel
        {% entry has been used so we want the "text" field
          \glsentrytext{\glslabel}\glsinsert
        }%
        {% entry hasn't been used so we want the "first" field
         % (and add \emph)
          \emph{\glsentryfirst{\glslabel}\glsinsert}%
        }%
      }%
      {% first letter upper case (\Gls)
        \ifglsused\glslabel
        {% entry has been used so use "text" field with the first letter
         % converted to upper case
           \Glsentrytext{\glslabel}\glsinsert
        }%
        {% entry hasn't been used so use the "first" field with the first
         % letter converted to upper case (and add \emph)
          \emph{\Glsentryfirst{\glslabel}\glsinsert}%
        }%
      }%
      {% all upper case (\GLS)
        \ifglsused\glslabel
        {% entry has been used, so use "text" field and convert to 
         % upper case
          \mfirstucMakeUppercase{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}\glsinsert}%
        }%
        {% entry hasn't been used, so use "first" field and convert
         % to upper case (and add \emph)
          \emph{\mfirstucMakeUppercase{\glsentryfirst{\glslabel}\glsinsert}}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  {% \glsdisp was used. The text is supplied in \glscustomtext
    \ifglsused\glslabel
    {\glscustomtext\glsinsert}%
    {\emph{\glscustomtext\glsinsert}}% add \emph on first use
  }%
}


\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{wombat}
{
  name={wombat},
  description={blah blah blah}
}

\begin{document}

\gls{wombat} should be all lowercase.

\Gls{wombat} should begin with an uppercase letter, but it doesn't!

Wombat.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The main reason for this complex method of formatting the entry is because it moves the case-changing as close as possible to the actual text that needs the case conversion and away from the variable formatting requirements that can break when used in the argument of `\makefirstuc` or `\MakeTextUppercase`.

Another possibility is to take advantage of the fact that all the `\gls`-like and `\glstext-like` commands use `\glstextformat` to format the entry text and the placeholder `\glslabel` is already set by the time `\glstextformat` is used. This means that `\glstextformat` can be redefined to reference the first use and determine whether to use `\emph`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\ifglsused\glslabel{#1}{\emph{#1}}}

\newglossaryentry{wombat}
{
  name={wombat},
  description={blah blah blah}
}

\begin{document}

\gls{wombat} should be all lowercase.

\Gls{wombat} should begin with an uppercase letter, but it doesn't!

Wombat.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Note that in this case, the font change will also apply to the commands that don't set or query the first use flag. This means that in the following, both `\glstext{wombat}` and the first instance of `\gls{wombat}` are emphasized:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\ifglsused\glslabel{#1}{\emph{#1}}}

\newglossaryentry{wombat}
{
  name={wombat},
  description={blah blah blah}
}

\begin{document}

\glstext{wombat}.

\gls{wombat} should be all lowercase.

\Gls{wombat} should begin with an uppercase letter, but it doesn't!

Wombat.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

With the `glossaries-extra` extension package, it's possible to refine `\glsentryfmt` so that only certain types of entries use a particular font on first use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \ifglshasshort{\glslabel}{\glssetabbrvfmt{\glscategory{\glslabel}}}{}%
  \glsifregular{\glslabel}%
  {%
     \glshasattribute{\glslabel}{firstfont}%
     {%
       \ifglsused{\glslabel}%
       {%
         \glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}%
       }%
       {%
         \csname\glsgetattribute{\glslabel}{firstfont}\endcsname
           {\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
       }%
     }%
     {\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
  }%
  {%
    \ifglshasshort{\glslabel}%
    {\glsxtrgenabbrvfmt}%
    {%
       \glshasattribute{\glslabel}{firstfont}%
       {%
         \ifglsused{\glslabel}%
         {%
           \glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}%
         }%
         {%
           \csname\glsgetattribute{\glslabel}{firstfont}\endcsname
             {\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
         }%
       }%
      {\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
    }%
  }%
}

\glssetcategoryattribute{animal}{firstfont}{emph}

\newglossaryentry{wombat}
{
  name={wombat},
  category=animal,
  description={blah blah blah}
}

\newglossaryentry{quartz}
{
  name={quartz},
  category=mineral,
  description={blah}
}

\begin{document}

\glstext{wombat}.

\gls{wombat} should be all lowercase.

\Gls{wombat} should begin with an uppercase letter, but it doesn't!

Wombat.

\gls{quartz}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This redefinition of `\glsentryfmt` allows the first use font to be supplied by the attribute `firstfont`. In the above example, I've set this attribute to `emph` for the `animal` category but not for the `mineral` category, so the first use of `\gls{wombat}` is emphasized but not for `\gls{quartz}` (and not for `\glstext{wombat}`)

[image: image of document]

I noticed that your MWE contains the `acronym` package option, so here's a modification to the example so that it includes an abbreviation that also uses `\emph` (for both the long and short form) on first use.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \ifglshasshort{\glslabel}{\glssetabbrvfmt{\glscategory{\glslabel}}}{}%
  \glsifregular{\glslabel}%
  {%
     \glshasattribute{\glslabel}{firstfont}%
     {%
       \ifglsused{\glslabel}%
       {%
         \glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}%
       }%
       {%
         \csname\glsgetattribute{\glslabel}{firstfont}\endcsname
           {\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
       }%
     }%
     {\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
  }%
  {%
    \ifglshasshort{\glslabel}%
    {\glsxtrgenabbrvfmt}%
    {%
       \glshasattribute{\glslabel}{firstfont}%
       {%
         \ifglsused{\glslabel}%
         {%
           \glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}%
         }%
         {%
           \csname\glsgetattribute{\glslabel}{firstfont}\endcsname
             {\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
         }%
       }%
      {\glsxtrregularfont{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
    }%
  }%
}

\glssetcategoryattribute{animal}{firstfont}{emph}

\newglossaryentry{wombat}
{
  name={wombat},
  category=animal,
  description={blah blah blah}
}

\newglossaryentry{quartz}
{
  name={quartz},
  category=mineral,
  description={blah}
}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\newacronym{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}

\renewcommand{\glsfirstabbrvdefaultfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\renewcommand{\glsfirstlongdefaultfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\begin{document}

\glstext{wombat}.

\gls{wombat} should be all lowercase.

\Gls{wombat} should begin with an uppercase letter, but it doesn't!

Wombat.

\gls{quartz}

First use abbreviation: \gls{html}.
Next use: \gls{html}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]